# Reading NULL bytes using pandas.read_csv()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a file in CSV format which contains NULL bytes (may be 0x84) in each line. I need to read this file using c engine of pd.read_csv() . 
This values causes an error while reading - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 14 .
Is there any way out to fix it without changing the file ?

Answer (score 1):

Try these options if it helps:

**Option 1:**

Set the engine as python.

```
pd.read_csv(filename, engine='python')
```

**Option 2:**

Try `utf-16` encoding, because the error could also mean the file is encoded in UTF-16. Or change the encoding to the correct format example

```
encoding = "cp1252"
encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
```

**Option 3:**

Read the file as bytes

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
  data = f.read()
```

That b in the mode specifier in the open() states that the file shall be treated as binary, so contents will remain a bytes. No decoding attempt will happen this way.

Alternatively you can use open method from the codecs module to read in the file:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
```

This will strip out (ignore) the characters and return the string without them. Only use this if your need is to strip them not convert them.
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type